# Strange json_encode behavior on Wordpress site

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I created a test page for image data. It will show a page of JSON image data in my browser. In my Firefox web developer console (see screenshot), I will see all sixty image urls show up, but what is bizarre is that about 15 or 16 Wordpress blog/post urls are also requested after the images. These urls are nowhere to be seen in the page source, so I have no idea how or why they are being requested by the browser. If the result format is not json encoded I don't see these extraneous posts showing up.

Here is my test code, stripped down to the barest essentials:

```
<?php

if( !empty($_REQUEST['json']) ){

    //get image data here
$images = array();
$imagesjson = file_get_contents('test.json'); 
$images = json_decode($imagesjson);
$result['images'] = $images;

// return results
if ($_REQUEST['json'] == 'json') {print_r(json_encode($result));} 
else {print_r($result);}

}

?>
```

You can see it in action here:

http://www.bangstyle.com/test/jsontest.php?json=json - json results

http://www.bangstyle.com/test/jsontest.php?json=nojson - non json results

I opened a Firefox web console (Tools->Web Developer->Web Console) and made sure only the "logging" and "net" buttons were selected, then loaded the jsontest.php file above with the different query strings. I saw in the first case about 16 blog articles were requested in addition to the images even though their urls are nowhere in the actual page (you can see 4 of them in this pic):

[image: Firefox console results]

With the non-json response these blog articles did not show up, which is what I want.

I just can't make sense out of what's happening. The result needs to be JSON but it should not be requesting these extra blog posts. Could some strange web server config be causing this?

Comment: The main thing I can tell you, is that none of this has anything in the world to do with json.  json is not a displayable web format.  It can't by itself trigger any behavior. All the information you provided in this question is of absolutely no value in understanding whatever it is that you're alluding to, which seems to be what your firefox console?  (do you mean the firebug console screen?) is displaying.  You haven't provided any information to help people understand what you're seeing either, but certainly more info about the viewer you're using, and in what mode and context is needed.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. Is the format wrong? Is the data wrong? What are you expecting instead of what you're getting?

Comment: I think it's Wordpress related, but have yet to find the root of the problem. The DATA itself is fine. It's just that, for whatever reason, when the data returned is json, additional GETs are made for blog posts even though the urls for these posts are not anywhere in the response. For whatever reason, when the exact same data is returned in array format, this doesn't happen. I am going to continue testing and report back here one I figure out what the heck is going on.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I hope my update makes more sense. I included the actual code I am using to test this, as well as a screenshot of the console.

Comment: The browser is just trying to load each `attachment_image_src` along with images in `attachment_image`'s (these obviously look like web addresses so it just tries to load their sources).

Comment: Since none of the blog urls are actually in the page source, I'm not sure I understand you. For example, here is one blog url that I see in the console: http://www.bangstyle.com/2012/04/wedding-hair-accessories/. If I look at the page source, this url cannot be found. I just don't see where it could be coming from.